# Find a list of non-duplicate numbers in a collection. Can this be done more efficient/shorter code?

Tags: c#

```
static IEnumerable<T> FindUniqueNumbersInCollection<T>(ICollection<T> value)
{
    Dictionary<T, byte> hash = new Dictionary<T, byte>();

    foreach (T val in value)
    {
        if (hash.ContainsKey(val)) { hash[val] = 1; continue; }
        hash.Add(val, 0);
    }

    List<T> unique = new List<T>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<T, byte> kvp in hash)
    {
        if (kvp.Value == 0) unique.Add(kvp.Key);

    }

    return unique;
}
```

Comment: which do you want: more efficiently OR shorter code?

Comment: Also note that it is suppose to be generic function definition but the site stripped my left and right arrows

Comment: @Kyle: They're called "carets". :) And it's because you hadn't indented it to make it look like code.

Comment: @Kyle: I fixed that for you a few minutes ago, you just need to refresh the page. (Which you should have done by the time you see this comment.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: No way, man, they're called angle brackets. Carets are the ones that point up ^

Comment: @BoltClock: [Search for `>` and `<`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/rksh.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit:

I think this is finally correct. :)

```
var dict = new Dictionary<T, bool>();
foreach (var v in value)
    dict[v] = dict.ContainsKey(v);
foreach (var pair in dict)
    if (!pair.Value)
        yield return pair.Key;  //Algorithmically, as fast as possible
```

Or if you'd like some LINQ:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<T, bool>();
foreach (var v in value)
    dict[v] = dict.ContainsKey(v);
return dict.Keys.Where(k => !dict[k]);  //*COULD* be slower on lots of collisions
```

Or even

```
var dict = new Dictionary<T, bool>();
foreach (var v in value)
    dict[v] = dict.ContainsKey(v);
return dict.Where(p => !p.Value).Select(p => p.Key); //"Fastest".. but not really
```

I wouldn't say it's "more efficient" than yours (it's really not -- they're pretty much the same), but it's definitely shorter.

---

If you want *overkill* efficiency (at the cost of accuracy), you can always use a Bloom Filter!

Comment: This code finds all the values in `value`, not just the ones that only appear once.

Comment: @recursive: OOOOOOOOHHHHHHHH D'OHH Now I see what Jon Skeet meant!! x___x

Answer (score 2):

Since you're returning an `IEnumerable<T>`, you could

```
return hash.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == 0).Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
```

instead of the second loop to perform that iteration lazily.

Comment: It could potentially save time, depending on what the caller does with the result.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm usually on the other side of this type of exchange, but I'm not really trying to pwn you.  Your new answer is quite nice btw.

Comment: lol, I didn't mean it in a bad way at all; your comment was excellent and spot-on! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do this (in one statement).

```
var unqiue = new[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4 }
    .GroupBy(x => x)             // groups the elements using the element value as the key
    .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)  // restricts to only those groups having a count of 1
    .Select(x => x.Key);         // selects the key from each of those groups
```

(You will need to have `using System.Linq;` in your code file.)

Although your ultimate goal is efficiency, I would use the simplest code possible (which I think this is) and then optimise when the profiler tells me to.